# Calculate % of row total in SAS visual Analytics

Tags: sas, aggregate, aggregate-functions, sas-visual-analytics

I am trying to create a table which has two categories - X an Y. I am trying to create a table in SAS visual analytics that tells me the share  of total in each category. My table looks something like this

| Category A | Catgeoy B | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40% | 60% | 100% |

I was trying to follow the below link but unfortunately my version of SAS VA does not have Aggregated measure ( tabular) option in it so I do not know how can I proceed forward with it.

How can i go about creating one without the aggregated tabular option

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/SAS-Visual-Analytics-Report-Example-Percent-of-Total-For-All-For/ta-p/636030

Comment: Are you using VA 7.5?

Comment: @StuSztukowski- yes ia m using SAS VA 7.5

Comment: @StuSztukowski- how to create this it in this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in VA 7.5, we'll use a Crosstab object, a transposed form of your data, and use the "Percent of row total" calculation option within the crosstab. Let's use the below data for our example:

```
data have;
   input id x y;
   datalines;
1 40 60
2 30 70
3 90 10
;
run;
```

**Step 1: Transpose to long and create by-groups**

Transpose your data so that it is in a long format, then load it and register it to LASR.

```
proc transpose data = have
               out  = want(rename=(COL1 = value))
               name = category
               ;
    by id;
    var x y;
run;
```

Output:

```
id  category    value
1   x          40
1   y          60
2   x          30
2   y          70
3   x          90
3   y          10
```

**Step 2: Create a crosstab**

Change `id` to a category, then create a crosstab that looks like this:

- **Columns**: category
- **Rows**: id
- **Measures**: value

[image]

Go to Options --> Scroll to the bottom --> expand "Totals and Subtotals," and Enable "Totals" for rows and set the Placement to "After."

[image]

**Step 3: Create a row-level Percent Calculation**

Right-click the header **value** within the table and select "Create and add calculation...".

[image]

Select "Percent of row total - Sum" under the "Type" drop-down menu.

[image]

Remove **Value** as a role from the crosstab graph, format **Percent** to have 0 decimal places, and you'll have a table with row-wise percentages.

[image]